# Eat all the circles MAZE

Tags: visual, mazes, pencil-and-paper-games

I made this maze-puzzle for my students.

**The goal is to draw a line through all of the circles.**

The rules:

- Start from the star
- At each intersection are arrows. You can only move through the intersection in accordance with the direction of the arrow.  (e.g see below pic: In below pic, once you reach the intersection you can only continue drawing down or to the right. You can not continue drawing up or to the left.) You must then continue on to the next intersection. (Meaning, you cant go through an intersection, hit the circle, then go back to that intersection.)

  [image]
- Can only draw in between the gray squares.
- Can not pick up the pen/pencil from the maze. Meaning: the line you are drawing must be continuous.
- Can not draw a line over any circle twice. (you can draw over a previous drawn line)
- You solve the puzzle once you have gone over every circle. There is no official end point.

Good Luck!

[image]

Comment: Im assuming you also end at the star?

Comment: No. You dont have to

Comment: Oh wear do you end then?

Comment: Once you draw over all the circles, you win

Comment: Also, I made a correction above; once you go through an intersection, you must continue on in that direction until you reach the next intersection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I switch from blue to orange and back at two circles just to avoid ambiguity in the path being taken...

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

### Solution:

> [image]

I found this using mostly trial and error after drawing in the mandatory segments through the circles.

Comment: Same looks like you beat me to it!

Comment: There are more solutions, for example you could loop around the bottom left block a few times, or go twice clockwise around the bottom right block, not to mention arbitrary back-and-forth across certain edges.