# Holiday Madness: Draw a line through all the gifts

Tags: grid-deduction, strategy, mazes, seasonal

Can you collect all the gifts?

The rules:

- Start from the star
- At each intersection are arrows. You can only move through the intersection in accordance with the direction of the arrow. (e.g If you hit an intersection with an arrow pointing down and to the left, when you hit that intersection you can only continue moving down or to the left) You must then continue on to the next intersection. (Meaning, you can't go through an intersection, hit the gift, then go back to that intersection.)
- Can only draw in between the gray squares.
- Can not pick up the pen/pencil from the maze. Meaning: the line you are drawing must be continuous.
- Can not draw a line over any gift twice. (you can draw over a previous drawn line)
- Goal: Collect all the gifts using the above rules and win!

[image]

Comment: I thought this looked familiar: this isn't Rudy's [first maze](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97110/eat-all-the-circles-maze)

Answer (score 7):

Here is my solution.  I found it mostly by trial and error.

I made the line change colour every once in a while so that it would be easier to distinguish different lines when they overlap.  Start at the star, with the green line.

<sup>*(Thanks to [Ben Barden](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/43561), who pointed out a small error in my original solution (and the way to fix it!))*</sup>

> [image]

Comment: there's a gift in the 4th column that gets hit by both light blue and yellow.

Comment: Fix that by diverting the yellow off to the right one intersection up, then back over to the left after droppign by one.

Comment: @BenBarden Thanks for pointing that out (and providing a way to resolve it!).  I've fixed it now.

Comment: You're now missing the gift on the last row.  You can fix that by extending that purple loop out one more to the right.

Comment: @BenBarden Man, good thing I have you around.  Not sure how I messed that up.  Thanks for pointing it out...

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to get as much progress as possible just by using logical deduction.
This is how far I got:

> First Step:
>  [image: Step 1]
>
>  Second Step:
>  [image: Step 2]

I solved the remaining path with a mix of trial and error, and logical deduction. I managed to find a path that begins and terminates at the star.

My solution:

> [image]